# A2C and stable_baselines3

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I´m trying to use this code from a repo in GitHub (https://github.com/nicknochnack/Reinforcement-Learning-for-Trading-Custom-Signals/blob/main/Custom%20Signals.ipynb) in Point 3:

```
model = A2C('MlpLstmPolicy', env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000000)
```

I got a lot of problems with stable-baselines for a different line so I tried with stable-baselines3
But I think that MlpLstmPolicy doesn´t work.
ChatGPT said to change this for:

```
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import CheckpointCallback

env = make_vec_env('env', n_envs=4, seed=0)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])

model = PPO('MlpLstmPolicy', env, verbose=1)
```

But I get this error: **Error: Attempted to look up malformed environment ID: b'env'. (Currently all IDs must be of the form ^(?:[\w:-]+/)?([\w:.-]+)-v(\d+)$.)**

I see that in the first option "model =" used env. So this is what I did.

I´ve changed "env" with everything else I found in the code but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Recurrent policies are not supported directly in sb3 yet, but you can use [`RecurrentPPO`](https://sb3-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo_recurrent.html) from sb3-contrib, I think that's what you want.